# How to require a gem in .irbrc without needing to also add it to a Rails Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, rubygems, irb

I've added [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print) to my `~/.irbrc` file like so:

```
require 'ap'
```

Inside a Rails project directory, if I run `irb` it loads the gem fine, because I've already installed the gem locally. But if I run `rails console`, it spits out this error:

```
cannot load such file -- ap
```

How can I resolve this? I am guessing that it's looking for the gem in the app's Gemfile, but I don't want to add it to the Gemfile because I don't want other developers requiring that dependency. I only want to use awesome_print on my machine.

I am also using rbenv, if that is of any help.

Answer (score 2):

There is this [trick](https://github.com/janlelis/debundle.rb).

What you need to do is

```
# Copy the definition of the debundle! method into your ~/.irbrc
# Call 'debundle!' from IRB when you need to.
```

(as explained at the top of the file)

The text as it appears on the referred to site:

---

`debundle.rb` allows you to require gems that are not in your `Gemfile` when inspecting
programs that are run with Bundler.

**Use at your own risk!**

Paste the code of debundle.rb and you are done! A good place would be your `.irbrc` file
before requiring [irbtools](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools).

The code is directly taken from [pry-debundle](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-debundle).
Please look there for any further information. This repo exists to simplify debundling
without using the `pry` repl.